# How will JDK9 modules help for 'package-scoped sub-packages'?

Tags: java, java-9

I am wondering about JDK9 modules. Say you have the following 3 packages:

```
com.company.product
com.company.product.impl_a
com.company.product.impl_b
```

Classes in package `product.impl_a` and `product.impl_b` can only be accessed by classes in package `product`. The user should only use classes from `product` package. You can imagine that passing certain flags or properties will decide whether `impl_a` or `impl_b` will be used, internally.

In JDK8-, you have to make these classes inside `impl_a` and `impl_b` `public`. This kinda *sucks*, because users can be tricked that they can use these classes. It's perfectly valid and allowed.

How can JDK9 help here? Will we declare a module for `product.impl_a` and another one for `product.impl_b` and declare that the exported classes are only to be accessed by a third module `product`, which will depend on the two modules `product.impl_a` and `product.impl_b`? In addition, it will be effectively impossible to declare a new module which will depend on `product.impl_a` or `product.impl_b`? Can other modules only depend on module `product`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in your question seems to indicate that these three packages need to end up in different JARs/modules. If they don't, simply put them into the same JAR, use the visibility modifiers as described, and use the following module declaration:

```
module com.company.product { 
    export com.company.product;
}
```

Then **within** module *com.company.product* you can use code from all packages as you normally would, but from **outside** only `com.company.product` is [accessible](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#exports-accessibility).

Comment: That makes sense. Is it also possible to use modules within one same JAR? That is, is it possible to export `com.company.product.impl_a` to `com.company.product` (and the same for `impl_b`)? This way, classes in `impl_b` can never use `impl_a` despite the public class in `impl_a`. (and vice versa).

Comment: No, in Java 9 there can only be one module per JAR. (There were some requests for so-called multi-module JARs, but I know of no plan to provide that feature.) If you want to isolate _impl_a_ from _impl_b_, you need to create different modules. Have a look at [services](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#services) for a way to decouple them, so _product_  does not need to know them.

Comment: Great link, this helps so much. THANKS

Answer (score 3):

You can let the classes within the packages `impl_a` and `impl_b` be `public` and to export packages to specific `module`s [(qualified exports)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#qualified-exports) further you can use the convention as :

```
exports com.company.product.impl_b to third.module;
```

So, in your case consider these

```
module first.module { 
    export com.company.product.impl_a to second.module;
    export com.company.product.impl_b to third.module;
}
```

which means that the package `com.company.product.impl_a` is **only** exported to the `second.module` which now when reads `first.module` has access to the public types of the classes within `impl_a` package and similarly `com.company.product.impl_b` is only exported to `third.module`.

Comment: I did not realize you could export to a specific module. THANKS

Comment: @KevinDeGrote That's actually a controlled access to the packages exported to a specific module.